# Capture every SOAP Message in a session?

Tags: soap, httpclient, soap-client

I am trying to analyze a browser-based Flash application that communicates to a backend with SOAP. What I'd like to do is capture each of the SOAP calls that are made - both the POSTed SOAP message and the response. I can see it in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/), or [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)'s Developer tools, but saving each call I'm not sure how to do.

Are there tools available to capture each call? I'd like to capture each SOAP call along with HTTP headers (including cookies) so I can look at them in something other than the tools in-browser?

I tried using [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) against the WSDL url but I'm getting errors indicating there are errors in the WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to take a look at a proxy.

Several that should suffice:

http://www.wireshark.org/

http://www.parosproxy.org/

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Are all these basically equivalent? Pluses and minuses to any of these?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried fiddler2, it works for me